# In Node, what is a good way to create a http connection with a 'wait for connection' timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

From a unit test I need to create an http connection (to a Chrome's --remote-debugging-port) and need a way to wait for the http based json service to be available.

I was not able to find an npm package that supported that case, the http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback doesn't seem to support connection timeouts, and the couple examples I saw where based on:

1. trying to make a connection to the target url
2. capture `req.on('error', function (err) {`
3. check for `err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'`
4. try again for x seconds at a y ms interval

Is that the best way to do it?

**Update 1:** setTimeout doesn't work because we get an exception if the target URL is not available

```
it 'connect_To_Chrome', (done)->
  url_Debug = "http://localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/json"
  url_Debug.GET (data)->
    assert_Is_Null(data)
    http = require('http')
    # throws error if the value is less that 60 (i.e. 60ms)
    (100).eval_After ->                 # setTimeout
      socket = http.get url_Debug, ->   # create socket
        console.log 'inside get'        # socket was created
      socket.setTimeout 400, ->         # try setTimeout
        console.log 'inside timeout'    # trigered after 400ms
        done()
```

in the code sample shown above, if the initial timeout is for example 10 (or not used at all), we will get the following exceptions

```
Error: socket hang up
  at createHangUpError (http.js:1476:15)
  at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1526:23)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

**update 2**: here is a fist pass at a solution

```
it 'get Chrome Remote Debugging /json', (done)->

  wait_For_Http_GET = (url, timeout, callback)->
    delay = 10;
    try_Http_Get = (next)   =>
      url.GET (data)        => if data is null then (delay).invoke_After next else callback(data)
    run_Tests = (test_Count)=> if test_Count.empty() then url.GET (callback) else try_Http_Get ()->run_Tests(test_Count.splice(0,1))
    run_Tests([0.. ~~(timeout/delay)])

  url_Debug = "http://localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/json"

  url_Debug.GET (data)->
    assert_Is_Null(data)
    wait_For_Http_GET url_Debug,100, (html)->
      data = JSON.parse(html)
      data.assert_Is_Array().assert_Size_Is(1)
      data[0].description         .assert_Is('')
      data[0].devtoolsFrontendUrl .assert_Is("/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/devtools/page/#{data[0].id}")
      data[0].id                  .split('-').assert_Size_Is(5)
      data[0].title               .assert_Is('')
      data[0].type                .assert_Is('page')
      data[0].url                 .assert_Is('nw:blank')
      data[0].webSocketDebuggerUrl.assert_Is("ws://localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/devtools/page/#{data[0].id}")
      done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to choose my **update 2** answer since it does works as I expected and answers the question

```
  wait_For_Http_GET = (url, timeout, callback)->
    delay = 10;
    try_Http_Get = (next)   =>
      url.GET (data)        => if data is null then (delay).invoke_After next else callback(data)
    run_Tests = (test_Count)=> if test_Count.empty() then url.GET (callback) else try_Http_Get ()->run_Tests(test_Count.splice(0,1))
    run_Tests([0.. ~~(timeout/delay)])
```

test

```
it 'get Chrome Remote Debugging /json', (done)->

  url_Debug = "http://localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/json"

  url_Debug.GET (data)->
    assert_Is_Null(data)
    wait_For_Http_GET url_Debug,100, (html)->
      data = JSON.parse(html)
      data.assert_Is_Array().assert_Size_Is(1)
      data[0].description         .assert_Is('')
      data[0].devtoolsFrontendUrl .assert_Is("/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/devtools/page/#{data[0].id}")
      data[0].id                  .split('-').assert_Size_Is(5)
      data[0].title               .assert_Is('')
      data[0].type                .assert_Is('page')
      data[0].url                 .assert_Is('nw:blank')
      data[0].webSocketDebuggerUrl.assert_Is("ws://localhost:#{nodeWebKit.port_Debug}/devtools/page/#{data[0].id}")
      done()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [`request.setTimeout()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) which allows you to set an idle timeout that fires if no data is sent or received on the underlying socket within the period of time you specify. This should also work before a connection is made.

You will also need to listen for the `error` event on the request object in case the connection is rejected sooner.

Comment: Hi, see 'update 1' above for a test that shows how I was not able to use setTimeout (am I using it wrongly?)

Comment: You need to listen for the `error` event on the request object too. The timeout is just a simple timer that fires after x milliseconds of socket inactivity, so if you get a socket error before then, you will have to handle that.